# Syntax rules for parentheses in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax, parentheses, iife

I'm curious about the syntax rules for parentheses in certain circumstances in JavaScript, such as in wrapping bits of code. I'm very familiar with using them for conditions, like `if(this) that` and to call functions, but there are a couple of other ways I've noticed myself using them and I don't actually know what the rule is, or if they're even connected.

What I've seen:

I've seen them used to wrap a function in IIFEs -the outside pair in `(() => { do something })();`, and also in implicit return statements from arrow functions when you want to break the line, like in React stateless functional components:

```
() => (
  <div>
    Hello World
  </div>
);
```

I'm also aware that you can wrap a condition in multiple parentheses (for no good reason) and it doesn't break anything: `if(((true)))`.

What I want to know:

I've discovered that I can't use parenthesis to organize my code just wherever I want to.

Are these all related? What is the rule for how/when you can wrap things? Is it all for organization's sake or is there sometimes a change in functionality (I'm thinking IIFEs in particular here)?

Thanks for any clarity on this!

Comment: The differences are three-fold: syntax, convention, and operator precedence. For example, parentheses are required to invoke a function or bind expression logic for if statements, loops, etc. They also define a function's parameter list. But they can also be used to force a certain order of operations, just like in mathematics. For example, `var x = 5 * 2 + 4` is not the same as `var x = 5 * (2 + 4)`.

Comment: Parentheses that do not enforce operator precedence or that which must be syntax-complient, are benign and they can be used as liberally as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some basic things, all different, that parentheses do:

1. Group subexpressions within a larger expression;
2. Delineate portions of some statement syntaxes (`for`, `while`, etc)
3. Delineate function call parameters
4. Delineate formal parameters in function declarations

It therefore does not really make sense to think about how parentheses can be used in a general sense, except in the first case (subexpression grouping). In that case, they work like parentheses in ordinary algebra.

In the other cases, the parentheses are part of the syntax, and they're not optional. Unfortunately in running code you can't tell one sort of parenthesis from another without simply knowing the syntax. So in

```
someFunction(x, (y + 1), z)
```

The parentheses around `y + 1` are optional, and part of the expression grammar, while those around the overall list of function arguments are not optional, being required for that subexpression to be a function call.

There's really no shortcut to becoming familiar with the details of JavaScript statement syntax.